# Wikidata: list every physical objects

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to get the name of the all physical things (tangible concepts) Wikidata knows about (objects, places, countries, etc), or in other words everything non-abstract.

There are examples close to what I need, but with only a depth of one: [all the things that are instances of phone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35118127/5404567).

I found [this example](https://query.wikidata.org/?query=%23Children+of+Genghis+Khan%0D%0A%0D%0A%23added+before+2016-10%0D%0A+%23defaultView%3AGraph%0D%0APREFIX+gas%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bigdata.com%2Frdf%2Fgas%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT+%3Fitem+%3FitemLabel+%3Fpic+%3FlinkTo%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++SERVICE+gas%3Aservice+%7B%0D%0A++++gas%3Aprogram+gas%3AgasClass+%22com.bigdata.rdf.graph.analytics.SSSP%22+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++++++gas%3Ain+wd%3AQ720+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++++++gas%3AtraversalDirection+%22Forward%22+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++++++gas%3Aout+%3Fitem+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++++++gas%3Aout1+%3Fdepth+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++++++gas%3AmaxIterations+4+%3B%0D%0A++++++++++++++++gas%3AlinkType+wdt%3AP40+.%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fitem+wdt%3AP40+%3FlinkTo+%7D%0D%0A++OPTIONAL+%7B+%3Fitem+wdt%3AP18+%3Fpic+%7D%0D%0A++SERVICE+wikibase%3Alabel+%7Bbd%3AserviceParam+wikibase%3Alanguage+%22en%22+%7D%0D%0A%7D#%23Children%20of%20Genghis%20Khan%0A%0A%23added%20before%202016-10%0A%20%23defaultView%3AGraph%0APREFIX%20gas%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.bigdata.com%2Frdf%2Fgas%23%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fpic%20%3FlinkTo%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20SERVICE%20gas%3Aservice%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20gas%3Aprogram%20gas%3AgasClass%20%22com.bigdata.rdf.graph.analytics.SSSP%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gas%3Ain%20wd%3AQ35120%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gas%3AtraversalDirection%20%22Forward%22%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gas%3Aout%20%3Fitem%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gas%3Aout1%20%3Fdepth%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gas%3AmaxIterations%204%20%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20gas%3AlinkType%20wdt%3A279%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP40%20%3FlinkTo%20%7D%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP18%20%3Fpic%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D) that searches with more depth and I modified the start point to [entity](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q35120):

```
#Children of Genghis Khan

#added before 2016-10
 #defaultView:Graph
PREFIX gas: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf/gas#>

SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?pic ?linkTo
WHERE
{
  SERVICE gas:service {
    gas:program gas:gasClass "com.bigdata.rdf.graph.analytics.SSSP" ;
                gas:in wd:Q35120 ;
                gas:traversalDirection "Forward" ;
                gas:out ?item ;
                gas:out1 ?depth ;
                gas:maxIterations 4 ;
                gas:linkType wdt:279 .
  }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P40 ?linkTo }
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P18 ?pic }
  SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

I still get no results.

Comment: This seems a too general question. I have tried several combinations querying for "physical object (Q223557)" and "entity (Q35120)" but I always get a timeout. Could you break down your query into separate pieces that make sense conceptually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in a comment, your question is too broad and you'll end up with too much answers

You look for the A that are instance of a subclass of B

so the query you point to is the right one

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item
WHERE {
   ?item wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q35120
}
```

the problem is the size
wd:Q35120 has a lot of subclasses
You can check that this way

```
SELECT ?a ?aLabel WHERE { ?a wdt:P279 wd:Q35120.
             SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}

SELECT ?a ?aLabel WHERE { ?a wdt:P279/wdt:P279? wd:Q35120.
             SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}

SELECT ?a ?aLabel WHERE { ?a wdt:P279/wdt:P279?/wdt:P279? wd:Q35120.
             SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

And so on : you'll see that there are already 40'000+ at forth level which is huge

You could also huge this nice tool to have a more precise view

https://tools.wmflabs.org/bambots/WikidataClasses.php?id=Q35120&lang=en

Comment: That is actually what I needed, I want millions of answers. I just need to do batching or use local copy of the data in order to not overload their server. Thanks!