# How to search entities by instance in Wikidata API

Tags: api, mediawiki-api, wikidata

I tried without success get this query:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=arturo&format=json&language=en&uselang=en&type=item

but only with elements from instance "human of", that means from `P31 : Q5`

Any help will be preciated because I can't find a way to set up those props.
This kind of query explodes in SPARQL but if someone has a relative answer to get the same result (search for all people with his name start with....) will be preciated too.

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/12497/16193

Comment: @StanislavKralin hi! thanks for your answers and comments. Take care that is not the same question, im trying to avoid sparql here.

Comment: Something like action=wbsearchentities&search=arturo&format=json&claim=p31:q5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really not sure that's possible with the Mediawiki API. It was not possible [a few years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886388/get-all-wikidata-items-that-are-an-instance-of-a-given-item) and I don't think the feature has been implemented since then.

But Open Refine has [a reconciliation service with Wikidata](https://tools.wmflabs.org/openrefine-wikidata/) based on an API that can filter by type ("instance of") or property. Its developer has not yet advertised it explicitly as a standalone API, but this is in project. Here is an example of use: find in Wikidata the people called "arturo" instances of human (Q5) and whose occupation (P106) is actor (Q33999).

```
https://tools.wmflabs.org/openrefine-wikidata/en/api?query={
                      "query":"arturo",
                      "limit":6,
                      "type" : "Q5",
                      "properties" : [
                         { "pid" : "P106" , "v" : "Q33999"}
                         ]
                         }
```

[Result.](https://tools.wmflabs.org/openrefine-wikidata/en/api?query=%7B%20%22query%22:%22arturo%22,%20%22limit%22:6,%20%22type%22%20:%20%22Q5%22,%20%22properties%22%20:%20[%20%7B%20%22pid%22%20:%20%22P106%22%20,%20%22v%22%20:%20%22Q33999%22%7D%20]%20%7D)

The main problem with this query is it will only return Arturos which are explicitly an instance of Q5. This will be the case of [this one](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q2865935), but not of those who are, for example, only instance of "film maker" (and it does not matter that film maker is himself a subclass of "human"). Sparql can handle class transitivity using the property paths (eg : wdt:P279*/wdt:P31*), but this API has not (yet) implemented them.

Comment: Thanks for response, but openrefine didn't help a lot. (Your answer helps anyway, thanks!) I've already tried. It lacks a lot of filters and data is not consistent because wikidata has a lot of problems with his elasticsearch motor. Actually, as you mentioned, this question has no answer at the moment, but thanks for your effort.